# Changing X-axis position in R barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have two values of averages `LR50<-(424.8, 425.7)`. I want to plot these as a barplot `barplot(LR50)`. Now, I don't need any of the information except from `ylim=c(424,426.5)`. When I change the x-axis `axis(1,at=c(0,10), pos=424)` there is still bar plot that falls below the axis.

How do I get the barplot to only plot from the new x-axis at y=424 and up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the `xpd` parameter (and set it to FALSE), this will clip the plot to the plotting region.

```
barplot(LR50,ylim = c(424,426.5),xpd=FALSE)
axis(1,at=c(0,10),pos=424)
```

[image]